# Android Firebase Database query returning null

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to query a Firebase Database but keep getting null returned. Here is what the database looks like:

[image]

And the Stem object:

```
public class Stem {
    private String stem;

    public Stem(){}

    public Stem(String stem){
        this.stem = stem;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return stem;
    }

    public void setText(String stem){
        this.stem = stem;
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity in the OnCreate

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mStemDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Stems");

 getStemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

if (mChildEventListener == null) {
                    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            Stem stem = dataSnapshot.getValue(Stem.class);
                            mStemAdapter.add(stem);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    };
                    mStemDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
                }

            }
        });
```

The query seems to access the database fine because it returns the Stems json array, but when it tries to add the stem to the adapter it returns stem as null. Any ideas?

Comment: On click useless here

Comment: either way it still doesn't return a Stem object

Comment: Maybe stemadapter not notifying changes. Print stem object with system.out.print to make sure it is not null

Comment: It's happening before the stem adapter. I think it has something to do with how it's reading the data from the database and trying to create the Stem object from it

Comment: Your `DatabaseReference` must specify the full path from the root. Is `pbandmath-febfc` your project root?  If not, correct your reference to include all path segments from the root to `Stems`.  Also, your `Stem` POJO doesn't follow the required naming conventions.  For field `stem` the getters/setters must be named `getStem()` and `setStem()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Firebase using **asynchronous** calls to access your database. As there is no OnComplete listener for this, you should notify your adapter for changes in the list. I was using RecyclerView when I faced this and just called `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter to update it with the fetched values.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the value under `Stems` in your database is recognized as an array instead of an object. It is because the key for the stems is an incrementing number.

You can try to do **Export JSON** from the Firebase Database console and see the structure of your database. The value you will get should be like this:

```
{
    "Stems": [
        null,
        { "stem": "Test for stem 1"},
        { "stem": "Test for stem 2"}
    ]
}
```

You can read more about Firebase behavior with Arrays [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

The solution for your problem is to use `databaseReference.push()` method to generate the key for the new stem. With the `push()` method, you don't have to remember the last key for the stem to increment it by 1. This `push()` method is also recommended by Firebase as the way to add new child item.

Example of `push()` method usage:

```
// create new Stem object
Stem stem = new Stem("Test for new stem");
// push new key under 'Stems' and then set the Stem object as value under the new key
mStemDatabaseReference.push().setValue(stem);
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT: If you don't want to change your database structure**

```
mStemDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<List<Stem>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Stem>>() {};
        List<Stem> stemList = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
        for (Stem stem : stemList) {
            if (stem != null) {
                mStemAdapter.add(stem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Forgive me as I'm new to Firebase, but isn't push for writing data to the database? I'm just trying to read it.

Comment: thanks, but I still can't seem to get it to work @Wilik. Is there a better way I should be structuring the database to make it easier to read?

Comment: can you explain what have you done or tried after reading my answer? I can't guess what problems you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the Firebase Query to a point later in the Activity load.  I had a similar issue when passing values via Intent, but the data wasn't returned from Firebase in time to load into the variables before the intent was executed.  Maybe you should create an initialization function and call that at the bottom of On Create.

```
init(){
...your code...
}
```