# firebase "Export JSON" not working for custom keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using custom numeric keys for storing data on certain node. When I download the data (export as JSON) from firebase console, the custom key information is lost!

Check this simple example:

[image]

The "Exported JSON" file does not contain the "keys". Instead it has this **null** value. Here is the file:

```
[ null, {
  "name" : "Pat"
}, {
  "name" : "Tom"
} ]
```

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: When the keys are integers, Firebase renders the data as an array.  Further explanation is at [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949220/android-firebase-database-query-returning-null/40950369#40950369

Answer (score 1):

Your "Exported JSON" file does not contain the "keys" because you set the keys as `integers` and not as `Strings`. To solve this problem is you need to use the `push()` method on your `reference`.

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();
```

In stead of having those custom keys you'll have the unique id's generated by the `push()` method. To get those unique keys you can use the `getKey()` method like this:

```
String uniqueId = yourRef.getKey();
```

The benefits of using this unique key are:

- Are unique
- The item are ordered by default in ascending order
- You'll get no errors when downloading the `JSON` file

Hope it helps.